# How to check the quality of image in react native like if I want to take 60%. Quality image so how to get it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

How to check the quality of image in react native like if I want to take 60%. Quality image so how to get it

I tried it through pixel resolution but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `react-native-image-picker` for uploading images, you can set maxWidth, maxHeight or quality of image for reducing the size in options.

```
const options = {
    title: 'Select Picture',
    storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
    },
    maxWidth: 500,
    maxHeight: 500,
    quality: 0.5,
};
```

Or if you want to fit in the image in any `View` you can use `resizeMode` property of `Image` which has the type `enum('cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can user react-native-image-picker library and can restrict user for image quality to upload and you can edit rest of the parameters on the basis of your requirements.

```
const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: "Images",
    allowsEditing: true,
    base64: true,
    quality: 0.6,
});

if (!result.cancelled) {
    const fileSize = result.base64.length * (3 / 4) - 2;
    if (fileSize > 6000000) {
        setFileSizeError(true);
    } else {
        setFileSizeError(false);
        const base64 = `data:image/png;base64,${result.base64}`;
        await dispatch(myExampleAction(base64));
    }
}
```